# How can I show a radio button as selected with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, selected, collection-select

So I have a form with multiple inputs.  for example:

```
<div class="grid_12">
  <%= f.input :status, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [ 'available', 'pending', 'rented','coming soon','off-market'], checked: @base_address.status %>
  <%= f.input :coop, as: :radio_buttons, collection: ['Cooperate with brokers','Keep in-house'], checked: @base_address.coop %>
    </div>
```

What I'm doing is cloning a listing and I want the previously selected values to show up as selected on my form when I click clone.  the first input for status works perfectly. status is a string.  the second one, coop, does not come through.  when I do an inspect in chrome I get this for the first one:

```
<input checked="checked" class="radio_buttons required" id="address_status_off-market" name="address[status]" required="required" type="radio" value="off-market">
```

but this for the second:

```
<input class="radio_buttons required" id="address_coop_cooperate_with_brokers" name="address[coop]" required="required" type="radio" value="Cooperate with brokers">
<input class="radio_buttons required" id="address_coop_keep_in-house" name="address[coop]" required="required" type="radio" value="Keep in-house">
```

not sure how one could work and not the other

Comment: Could be a problem with the string comparison in simple_form.  The first input are simple strings but the second input are more complex strings.  Might want to try eliminating issues around that first.